# C++ Linux X11 overlay rotate 45 orientation

Tags: c++, x11

I want the overlay image made of X11 to rotate 45 ~ 90 degrees

The operating system I am using is Linux for vscode c++

```
    display = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPLAY"));
    if (!display) 
    {
        std::cout << "opening X display... FAILED" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(display);
    rootWindow = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XMatchVisualInfo(display, screen, 32, TrueColor, &visualInfo);

    XSetWindowAttributes attributes;
    attributes.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, rootWindow, visualInfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attributes.border_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screen);
    attributes.background_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screen);
    attributes.override_redirect = true;

    unsigned long attrMask = CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel | CWOverrideRedirect;
    window = XCreateWindow(display, rootWindow, x, y, width, height, 0, visualInfo.depth, 
    InputOutput, visualInfo.visual, attrMask, &attributes);

    XserverRegion region = XFixesCreateRegion(display, NULL, 0);
    XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(display, window, ShapeInput, 0, 0, region);
    XFixesDestroyRegion(display, region);

    XMapWindow(display, window);
```

I solved the orientation, but it doesn't rotate

Comment: What code is supposed to rotate the overlay?

Comment: @AdrianMaire  ↓ code ↓